# Reverse for 'finished' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['finished/(?P<task_id>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have tried various patterns of solutions but for some reason they don't work. Below I attached the pieces of code that I think are contributing to the error. I have included the full view file that renders list.html

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def main(request):
    form = taskForm()

    context = {
        'doItems': task.objects.all(),
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'todoList/list.html', context)

@require_POST
def addToDO(request):
    form = taskForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        items = task(title = request.POST['title'], category = request.POST['category'], description = request.POST['description'])
        items.save()

    return redirect('main')


def completedToDO(request, task_id):
    items = task.objects.get(pk = task_id)
    items.finished = True
    items.save()

    return redirect('main')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name = 'main'),
    path('add', views.addToDO, name = 'add'),
    path('finished/<task_id>', views.completedToDO, name = 'finished'),
]
```

list.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <a href = "{% url 'finished' task_id %}" onMouseOver = "style.transform='scale(1.1,1.1)'" onMouseOut = "style.transform='scale(1,1)'" ><li class="list-group-item"> {{ items.title }} <b> {{ items.category }} </b>  <br> {{ items.description }} <br> <hr> {{ items.date }}</li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you share the view that renders `list.html`? `task_id` is either null or not in the context

Comment: I have edited the views to show it in entirety

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass value of `tasks.id` to the url. You can try like this(assuming `item` variable is an instance of Task class):

```
<a href = "{% url 'finished' items.id %}" onMouseOver = "style.transform='scale(1.1,1.1)'" onMouseOut = "style.transform='scale(1,1)'" ><li class="list-group-item"> {{ items.title }} <b> {{ items.category }} </b>  <br> {{ items.description }} <br> <hr> {{ items.date }}</li></a>
```